# I want a powerpoint slide to automatically open a word document in another window

Tags: vba, ms-word, powerpoint

I have a powerpoint slide show with lyrics to songs that I display on a projector. I also have a folder with Word documents that contain the lyrics and chords to the songs that a musician needs to perform the songs. I'd like to be able to open the slide show, run it in presenter mode(have the option to select slides from the list) and when I select a slide to display on the projector, I'd like for the corresponding Word document to open on another screen. My setup is laptop display for presenter mode, projector for lyrics for the congregation and monitor for displaying the Word document containing lyrics with chords. I'd like for the vba to close any open Word document without closing Word(so it will stay where I placed it on the display) and open the word document corresponding to the slide.

It was finding word open, but I couldn't see any word visible. When I went to task Manager, there were 12 winword.exe's running. I killed them all and then modified the code and it started doing what I wanted it to do.

```
Public Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()
On Error Resume Next
Dim i As Integer
i = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition
If IsNull(Application.Presentations(1).Slides(i).Shapes.Range(Array("WordLoc")).TextFrame.TextRange.Text) Then
Exit Sub
End If
Dim wdApp As Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If Not wdApp Is Nothing Then
wdApp.Documents.Close (wdDoNotSaveChanges)
On Error GoTo 0
Else
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Application.Presentations(1).Slides(i).Shapes.Range(Array("WordLoc")).TextFrame.TextRange.Text, , True)
On Error GoTo 0
wdApp.Visible = True
wdDoc.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: This is what I've come up with and it doesn't work. I don't see Word Opening.

Comment: `Error = 0` indicates no error, so the preceding lines run OK. If you don't get `MsgBox 4`, that means the preceding line is causing an error. It might be because there is no document to close. Try using `If wdApp.Documents.Count > 0 then wdApp.Documents.Close (wdDoNotSaveChanges)`